# Add button class active if url page have him class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, url

After load page i try add to my one button filter add class active if him class is correct with url.

My url filter is:

`www.mypage.com/animals?type=cat`

My button filter:

```
<a href="www.mypage.com/animals?type=cat"><button type="button" class="button">Cat</button></a>
<a href="www.mypage.com/animals?type=dog"><button type="button" class="button">Dog</button></a>
<a href="www.mypage.com/animals?type=fish"><button type="button" class="button">Fish</button></a>
```

How i can using JS or Jquery after load page add to my button cat if url is mypage.com/animals?type=cat class active?

Any ide?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var type = url.searchParams.get("type");
if(type === "cat"){
  document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].classList.add("active");
}
```

Further add 'else if' condition for the rest of the options too, i.e. dog and fish.

PS: Change the index too, for the dog it's [1] and for fish it's [2].